# Why is the isomorphism $\phi(x + \mathbb{Z}) = e^{2\pi xi}$ natural?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G = \mathbb{R}$, $H = \mathbb{Z}$. The quotient group $G/H$ is isomorphic to the circle subgroup $S^1$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^\times$. Why is the isomorphism $\phi : G/H \rightarrow S^1$, $\phi(x + \mathbb{Z}) = e^{2\pi xi}$ a "natural" choice in the sense that is the "obvious" one to take? For instance, if we are told that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $S^1$, what intuition would lead us to the $\phi$ described above?

Comment: Well, what other choice would you suggest?  "Natural" here doesn't have any technical meaning.

Comment: $G/H$ is essentially the interval $[0,1)$ under addition modulo $1$. Now bend that interval into a circle and connect both ends...

Comment: @EricWofsey Added verification to the question to address your concern.

Comment: @Bungo Sorry about your edit, I didn't see it while making my own, feel free to redo it if you wish.

Comment: @Bungo $G/H$ can be rewritten as the set $\{\mathbb{Z} + x | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. So if we set $x = 0$ (since it doesn't really matter) and scale $\mathbb{Z}$, we end up with the interval $[0, 1)$, where $1$ would have previously been "infinity"?

Comment: Think about how addition works in $G/H$. If we let $[x]$ be shorthand for $x + \mathbb Z$, then for example $[1/2] + [2/3] = [7/6] = [1/6]$. Once we get past $1$, we "wrap around" starting at $0$ again as if we were on a circle. This is similar to clock arithmetic: $11 + 2 = 13$ aka $1$. So in that sense it's natural to identify $G/H$ with arithmetic on a circle, and the map $[x] \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ is a convenient way to do that.

Comment: @Bungo Fantastic, this is precisely the kind of intuition that I was looking for. It seems that one of the missing parts for me was the fact that $\mathbb{Z} + a$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ again in this case. Your reduced notation and addition modulo $1$ helped me see that. Please do go ahead and post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how addition works in $G/H$. If we let $[x]$ be shorthand for $x + \mathbb Z$, then for example $[1/2] + [2/3] = [7/6] = [1/6]$. Once we get past $1$, we "wrap around" starting at $0$ again as if we were on a circle.

This is similar to clock arithmetic on an analog clock, which works modulo $12$, for example $[11] + [2] = [13] = [1]$.

So in that sense it's natural to identify $G/H$ with arithmetic on a circle, and the map $[x] \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ is a convenient way to do that. It simply maps $[x]$ to the point whose angle is $2\pi [x]$ on the unit circle.